# finding an integrating factor for the nonlinear non-autonomous ODE $ (xy)y'+y\ln y - 2xy = 0 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I though i might refresh my ODE knowledge a bit and decided to try the following exercise from "Advanced mathematical methods for scientists and engineers" by C. Bender and S. Orszag

> Solve the following ODE using an integrating factor of the form $I=I(y)$:
>
> $$ (xy)y'+y\ln y - 2xy = 0 \tag{ODE} $$

Clearly (ODE) is not exact. The integrating factor $I$ is a function such, that
$$ I(y)\left((xy)y'+y\ln y - 2xy\right) = \frac{d}{dx}F(x,y) $$
for some $F$. The solutions of (ODE) are thus given by $ F(x,y)=c $.$^\dagger$ Some initial tests suggested, that $I$ is non-trivial, consider therefore the following necessary and sufficient condition

> $$M(x,y) + N(x,y)y' = 0$$ is exact iff $$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}M(x,y) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}N(x,y)$$

In our case this gives

$$ M=I(y) \left(y \ln y - 2xy\right) \quad\quad N=I(y)xy $$
$$ \Rightarrow I'(y)+I(y)\cdot \frac{\ln y - y + 1-2x}{y\ln y-2xy} = 0 $$

which can formaly be integrated, but does not have a closed algebraic expression.

Did I do anything wrong so far? Am I missing a more obvious integrating factor or is this really the solution Bender and Orszag had in mind?

---

$^\dagger$ $F$ in general depends on $x$, $y$ and the derivatives of $y$. As the highest derivative must be lower than the order of the ODE though, only $y$ itself remains in our case.

Comment: @Maesumi $\frac{\partial}{\partial y} M = I'(y\ln y-2xy)+I(\ln y + 1 -2x) $. So I divided the whole equation by the factor next to the $I'$ to isolate the $I'$. What did you do with it?

Comment: my mistake! Oddly  enough you can factor a $y$ from the equation and get a simpler equation for I. But still no closed form.

Comment: It does not look like there is an analytical solution to this one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can find an obvious integrating factor for this ODE.

$xyy'+y\ln y-2xy=0$

$x\dfrac{dy}{dx}+\ln y-2x=0$

$x\dfrac{dy}{dx}=2x-\ln y$

$(2x-\ln y)\dfrac{dx}{dy}=x$

Let $u=x-\dfrac{\ln y}{2}$ ,

Then $x=u+\dfrac{\ln y}{2}$

$\dfrac{dx}{dy}=\dfrac{du}{dy}+\dfrac{1}{2y}$

$\therefore2u\left(\dfrac{du}{dy}+\dfrac{1}{2y}\right)=u+\dfrac{\ln y}{2}$

$2u\dfrac{du}{dy}+\dfrac{u}{y}=u+\dfrac{\ln y}{2}$

$2u\dfrac{du}{dy}=\dfrac{(y-1)u}{y}+\dfrac{\ln y}{2}$

$u\dfrac{du}{dy}=\dfrac{(y-1)u}{2y}+\dfrac{\ln y}{4}$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.

In fact all Abel equation of the second kind can be transformed into Abel equation of the first kind.

Let $u=\dfrac{1}{v}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{du}{dy}=-\dfrac{1}{v^2}\dfrac{dv}{dy}$

$\therefore-\dfrac{1}{v^3}\dfrac{dv}{dy}=\dfrac{y-1}{2yv}+\dfrac{\ln y}{4}$

$\dfrac{dv}{dy}=-\dfrac{v^3\ln y}{4}-\dfrac{(y-1)v^2}{2y}$

Please follow the method in http://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijmms/2011/387429/#sec2